# Too many redirects - Magento administartion Categories page

Tags: magento2.3, migration, redirection

Visiting `Catalog > Inventory > Products` in magento administration ends to a page with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error message.

Here's a screenshot from browser console.

[image]

I have tried to clear browser cache and cookies.

This happens only in Categories page.

The issue appeared after migrating product data from magento1 website.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Any custom rewrite rule in .htaccess file?

Comment: @RakeshGangani nothing special. also htaccess file hasn't changed the past months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting the correct root category entity id the store_group table data.

Check the second root category id in table `catalog_category_entity` (in my case it was 3):

[image]

and insert that id in `store_group` table for main website store:

[image]